# check if string contains back slash

Tags: c++, qt

I use a file dialog to get the file name.  Then I use this name in processing.  My problem is the file name contains backslash char `\` and when we use a path in any programming language we must change the `\` character to `\\`.  How can we solve this problem with back slash?

Comment: That is only necessary for string literals in code, not for strings that are created at runtime.

Comment: that mean if i store a path in QSting and use it in another place ,does not make any problem ?!!

Comment: I don't know whether your language lacks capital letters and punctuation, but English has a capital letter at the start of each sentence and sentences end in full stops. They also tend not to run on for ever.

Comment: It is `QString`, not "QSting". Please become accustomed to _precision_ and _accuracy_ when you work in programming.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: ROTFL, but fair enough. I dislike illiterate id... silliness myself, too.

Comment: When you input filenames from console or a file, you can replace a backslash, \, with a forward slash, /.  Many operating systems recognize the forward slash.

Comment: If you're using Qt's QFile, note that the backslash character is not supported in filenames for cross-platform compatibility reasons: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfile.html#details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when we use a path in any programming language we must change '\' char to "\"

That is not true.

First of all, escaping backslashes takes place by adding another backslash, not by replacing single quotes with double quotes. That's nonsensical.

Secondly, every programming language is different so many broad generalisations about what you need to do in "any programming language" is absurd.

Furthermore, in C++, only when writing characters into a *string literal* do you need to escape backslashes, because in string literals unescaped backslashes allow you to enter unreadable/unwriteable characters directly into your source code. But once the resulting string is in memory, it really doesn't matter that it contains backslashes.

**You do not have to change anything.**

Answer (score 0):

If [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) answered your question you should accept the answer.

I suspect that you're actually trying to ask about an opperating system independent file path, as is mentioned by: [Thomas Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225074/thomas-matthews).

If that is the case you should take advantage of [`QFileInfo`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfileinfo.html)

Alternatively you can use [`boost.filesystem.path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path) is a good alternative as well which I understand will be pulled into the C++17 standard.